# How to add second level to a submenu in a dropdown navigation css

Tags: css, navigation, drop-down-menu

I have created the navigation menu listed below:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index.php" target="_self" >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="preparation.php" target="_self" >Gallery</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="digital.php" target="_self">Storybooks</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="preparation.php" target="_self">Preparation</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="ceremony.php" target="_self">Ceremony</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="private.php" target="_self">Personal Shooting</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="firstdance.php" target="_self">First Dance</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="details.php" target="_self">Details</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="login.php" target="_self" >Customers</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.php" target="_self" >About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.php" target="_self" >Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS for this menu at the moment is:

```
.menu {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #6D6D6D;
}
.menu ul {
    height: 26px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}
.menu li a {
    color: #6D6D6D;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:hover, .menu ul li:hover a {

    background: #ca9875 url("menu_images/hover.gif") bottom center no-repeat;
    color: #6D6D6D;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li ul {
    /*background:#333333;*/
    /*background: #B32267;*/
    background: white;
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    /*width: 225px;*/
    width: 135px;
    z-index: 200;
    /*top:1em;
     /*left:0;*/
}
.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.menu li li {
    background: url('menu_images/sub_sep.gif') bottom left no-repeat;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    /*width: 225px;*/
    width: 135px;
}
.menu li:hover li a {
    background: none;
}
.menu li ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
    text-align: left;
}
.menu li ul a:hover, .menu li ul li:hover a {
    background: #ca9875 url('menu_images/hover_sub.gif') center left no-repeat;
    border: 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu p {
    clear: left;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to add second-level submenu to the category "Storybooks"? What i mean is that I would like to view another submenu in the right while i hover the mouse over the "Storybooks". Is this possible with css? 
Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: So it is not possible with css to add another <ul></ul> inside the <li>Storybooks</li> ?

Comment: You can not ADD <ul> with CSS, you can rather style the <ul> if you insert it in HTML. ;) See my answer for details.

Comment: Yes, i mean adding <ul> with html and style it accordingly. Thanks Paul,your answer works like a charm. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your code above to make it work, see http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/1/ for the new code.

Note: I added two menu points below Storybooks called Storybook 1 and Storybook 2. CSS is added to the bottom of the existing code (nothing altered above).

EDIT: You should clear up your CSS code a bit, e.g. use CSS selectors like `>` to match specific DOM levels.

Comment: You beat me to it with the same solution.

Comment: Paul, if wish to extend storybook1 and storybook2 to other submenus how should i follow?

Comment: Actually the same. Just insert yet another <ul> into any <li> and adjust your CSS.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/4/ for new version with an extra submenu for Storybook 1. Note that CSS becomes really ugle (quick & dirty) and should be simplified.

Comment: Indeed,i really need to simplify it. Thanks again, awesome help.

Comment: Hi again, i have made a few improvements on the menu but still i cannot further extend correctly any subcategories (with section 1 and section 2) under /gallery/weddings/storybook/. Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/20/ I would appreciate any help.Thanks!

Comment: Looks ok to me, I can go down to Gallery > Weddings > Storybook > Atrium Palace > Section 1/2.