# stuck Creating Submenus Using CSS

Tags: html, css

i am pretty new to css and html i designed a menu using css and even after searching a lot on internet i couldnt find a way to add submenus to it. they would never appear or even is they would they would overlap my horizontal menu instead of going vertical

heres the css of my menu :

```
#top-menu { float: left; width: 1000px; height:51px; margin-top: -30px; margin-left: 250px;  }


#top-menu ul {  list-style: none;text-align:center;
}

#top-menu li a{ position: relative; float :left;
display: block;
height: 32px;
width: 100px;
padding-top: 15px;
color: #444;
text-transform: none;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;

}

#top-menu li a:hover {
color: #f4f4f4;
background: #222;
border-bottom: 4px solid #22aed6; font-weight: bold;}

#top-menu li .active {
color: white;
background: #22aed6;
border-bottom: 4px solid #22aed6;}
```

and the html code :

```
<div id="top-menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="ff.html">Featured</a></li>
    <li><a href="f-e.html">Fests</a></li>
    <li><a href="fye.html">find</a></li>
    <li><a href="tip-us.html">tip US</a></li>
    <li><a href="adwus.html">Advertise</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

please help me out in creating submenus !

a link to my site is http://eventsindu.com (old design )
                     http://eventsindu.com/test ( the new design m working on)

Comment: Search on google "two level drop down menu css"

Answer (score 0):

To make a submenu, simply do like this.

```
<ul id="mainMenu">
    <li><a>blabla</a>
         <ul id="subMenu">
             <li><a>blabla2</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Go see this code for the CSS and more indepth http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/1/

Found it searching google for 10 seconds.

[How to add second level to a submenu in a dropdown navigation css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121146/how-to-add-second-level-to-a-submenu-in-a-dropdown-navigation-css)

Comment: Your answer is incorrect - the only acceptable children element of `<ul>` is `<li>`.

Comment: An anchor tag can't be a direct child of a UL.

Comment: I edited cause I forgot some tags but this should work. Edit : oops, stupid me put the <a> in the ul. Thank you for calling me on that silly error.